# Acessar banco SQLite em outra activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Estou começando em java android, sou bastante leigo ainda, estou pegando o conceito de POO aos poucos.

Meu problema é o seguinte, tenho uma classe CriaBanco e outra BancoController onde eu tenho alguns métodos para manipular o banco, isso em uma activity com nome menu, ate aqui tudo funcionando.

A dúvida e caso eu precise manipular os dados do banco em outra activity, qual a maneira correta de se fazer isso.

De início pensei em repetir a classe na outra activity mas fiquei com receio de fazendo isso: o banco ia ser reescrito e também achei deselegante repetir todo o código.
Então pensei se não tem uma maneira de instanciar essa classe na outra activity.

Abaixo o código que usei de criação e manipulação do banco, só o básico, removi os métodos para não ficar extenso.

```
public class BancoController {


    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private CriaBanco banco;

    public BancoController(Context context) {

        banco = new CriaBanco(context);
    }



}

public class CriaBanco extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "dbcoletor.db";

    public CriaBanco(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i2) {
        //--nothing for now--
    }
}
```

Para resolver eu criei uma classe na outra activity e usei essa forma:

```
private SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase("data/data/com.coletorrc/databases/dbcoletor.db", null);
```

Assim eu pude manipular o banco, apesar de funcionar fiquei pensando se não teria uma forma mais elegante de fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
// Criar os objetos do banco na sua Activity
CriaBanco helper = new CriaBanco(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

...

// Manipular o banco com query, insert, delete ou update     
Cursor cursor = db.query(...);
...
cursor.close();

...

db.insert(...);
db.delete(...);
db.update(...);

...

// Fechar a conexão com o banco quando terminar o uso
db.close();
```

Se quiser ainda mais elegância, dê uma olhada nos ContentProviders, rs:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Marcio, so que preciso disso para a outra activity, a classe CriarBanco no meu caso esta em uma activity, que ao clicar em um botao passa pra outra, nessa outra que preciso manipular o banco, aproveitando...se eu Instanciar essa classe CriarBanco mais de uma vez...ou entao em outra activity, ela sobrescreve o banco criado?

Comment: Você pode criar a classe CriaBanco separada (cria um arquivo próprio, para ficar mais organizado) e instanciá-la onde for necessário. O banco não será sobrescrito.

Comment: Consegui fazer como me indicou.

Answer (score 1):

Não é regra, mas o habitual e o mais "simples" é fazer o que você fez: uma classe herdada de SQLiteOpenHelper e, eventualmente, outra com métodos para aceder/manipular os dados no banco.
Essas classes não devem ser declaradas na Activity mas sim em arquivos java separados. Assim, pode facilmente obter uma instância delas em qualquer activity/classe.

Normalmente, tanto uma como a outra são *singleton* e apenas a segunda é que usa a primeira.

Todo o acesso e manipulação dos dados no banco é efectuado usando a segunda.

É claro que pode prescindir da segunda passando os seus métodos para a  primeira.

O mais importante aqui é ter apenas uma instância de SQLiteOpenHelper, cuja principal responsabilidade seja gerir a criação/versão do banco e disponibilizar um objecto do tipo SQLiteDatabase, através dos métodos `getWritableDatabase()` e/ou `getReadableDatabase()`.

Veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/182083/2541) um exemplo.

Comment: Desculpe a "Leiguice", na activity principal, eu tenho a classe que manipula o banco, com os metodos que preciso, quero saber se e possivel eu utilizar esses métodos em uma outra activity, no caso na classe que controla o banco tenho um metodo inserir, queria saber se tem uma forma de usar esse metodo em uma outra activity sem precisar reinscreve-lo, atualmente meu codigo esta funcionando, so estou tentando melhora-lo.

Comment: Essas classes não devem ser "escritas" na activity mas sim em arquivos java separados. Veja a edição da resposta.

Comment: Obrigado ramaral, criei um arquivo java separado e consegui o que precisava.